# Tokenizing text during parsing in C++, a newbies ordeal

Tags: c++, parsing, text, boost

I have a text file with some information I need to parse and put in to the appropriate array-like structure (I'm guessing these are vectors, in C++).

The text file I am trying to parse contains doubles, ints, and whitespaces that I'd like to ignore.

I have some experience with Python, and with Python one would use the split() method.

In C++, I can use boost tokenizer, or many other set of tools. I have tried many of these methods, but on my best attempt, I end up get a number like this "-97.653632.431542" which I don't even know how C++ allowed two decimal points. (I'm aware that the problem is my inexperience, not C++!)

So now on the the good stuff. First let's define the contents of the text file, which includes variable number of whitespaces, so I will put a few lines for illustration, with X number of whitespaces included at the beginning, (which I know I can get rid of using `boost::trim_left()`, but I wanted to include them here for the sake of example completeness).

**Note**: I am allowed to use any library I want, but if possible, I'd like to see both a canonical solution (so I can learn the canonical C++ way) and also a more practical solution using any other libraries that are common in C++, so I can also learn how to do it in a more practical way.

Text file contents:

```
FILE_DESCRIPTION
523459 45267393
         1  -91.1960210000   30.4248000000    6.9067078000
         2  -91.1936990000   30.4238730000    0.2607690100
         3  -91.1983420000   30.4257270000   11.4345030000
         4  -91.2006640000   30.4266540000    8.2591810000
         5  -91.2029850000   30.4275810000    2.2204340000
         6  -91.2043510000   30.4258950000    3.0012660000
         7  -91.1962610000   30.4231880000   13.4529710000
         8  -91.1941710000   30.4215120000    7.8915730000
```

Now the code to parse the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class myParserClass{
    public:
        std::string path;
        std::vector<int> NODE_INDEX;
        std::vector<double> X, Y, Z;
        std::string DESCRIPTION;
        int NE, NP;
        myParserClass(){};
        myParserClass(std::string path){
            parse_file(path)};

        void parse_fort14(std::string path){
            std::ifstream filei(path.c_str());
            std::string DESCRIPTION;
            getline(filei, DESCRITION);
            this->DESCRIPTION=DESCRIPTION;
            int NP, NE;
            stream >> NE >> NP;
            this->NE=NE;
            this->NP=NP;
            stream.str("");
            stream.clear();
            for(int x=0, x=NP, x++){
            // I'm having trouble here....
            this->NODE_INDEX=NODE_INDEX.push_back(node_index);
            this->X=X.push_back(x);
            this->Y=Y.push_back(y);
            this->Z=Z.push_back(z);};
        };
int main (){myParserClass myInfo("/path/to/myInfo.txt");}
```

Coding style comments are also welcome, since I am so new at C++, and everything is rough around all edges for me. Please note that I have stripped off from the example the file open checking statement and the while{} EOF statement for simplicity.

**EDIT 1:**
So it looks like what is happening before is relevant. I have edited the question above to reflect a more accurate version of the same question.

Comment: I don't have a problem with down votes, but if you downvote me, and don't explain why, it will only take me longer to correct my mistakes for the future.

Comment: Not the downvoter but here is my guess: the text is too long, not clear what the problem is, not a single question mark in your post. The [std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) basics, stream modifiers and string parsing have been covered multiple times. But long and unnecessary sentences in text mostly.

Comment: you re getting "-97.653632.431542"  for which value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contents have the same format (int, double, double, double) in each row, you can just use the stream operator as in:

```
int no;
double d1, d2, d3;
filei >> no >> d1 >> d2 >> d3;
```

And to read the whole file, a simple while loop is sufficient:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream filei("/path/to/myInfo.txt");
    int no;
    double d1, d2, d3;
    while (filei >> no >> d1 >> d2 >> d3) {
        // do something with data
    }
}
```

No fancy parsing required.

---

To have the row data combined, you may use a struct instead and use a vector of these structs:

```
struct row {
    int no;
    double x, y, z;
};

std::vector<row> rows;
// ...
row r;
while (filei >> r.no >> r.d1 >> r.d2 >> r.d3) {
    rows.push_back(r);
}
```

---

The next step could be implementing a stream operator for the row struct:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &f, row &r)
{
    return f >> r.no >> r.d1 >> r.d2 >> r.d3;
}
```

and use this in the loop:

```
row r;
while (filei >> r) {
    rows.push_back(r);
}
```

---

When you want to read a given number of lines, e.g. `NP` lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NP; ++i) {
    // read and process line
}
```

Although this is C++ 101, which you should learn before from a book or an online resource.

Comment: The file contents is not fixed. This is just a segment of the file. I think I had tried this, but I will double check...

Comment: And how do the other segments look like?

Comment: I took some time to edit my question so I can be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: With the first two header rows handled upfront, you can still read the rest of the file with such a while loop.

Comment: Yes, sort of, bu there are more sections below to parse. Once I get the hang on parsing, I think I will be able to gain more traction. I have a few more files I need to parse.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the "canonical C++" method. Here's a demo using Boost Spirit Qi:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c45fba3068b9a596)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct Fort14 {
    std::string description;
    int n_edges, n_points;

    struct Point { double x,y,z; };
    std::vector<Point> points;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Fort14::Point, x, y, z)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Fort14, description, n_edges, n_points, points)

Fort14 parse_fort14(std::istream& is) {
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    rule<It, std::string()> description = *(char_ - eol);
    It f(is >> std::noskipws), l;

    Fort14 data;
    if (phrase_parse(f, l, 
                description >> eol >>
                int_ >> int_ >> eol >>        // NE, NP
                (omit[int_] >> auto_) % eol,  // point data
            blank, data))
    {
        return data;
    }

    auto frag = f;
    for (int i = 10; i>0 && frag!=l; --i)
        ++frag;

    throw std::runtime_error("Parse error at " + std::string(f, frag) + "...");
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    auto parsed = parse_fort14(ifs);

    std::cout << "Description: '" << parsed.description << "'\n";
    std::cout << "n_edges: "      << parsed.n_edges     << "\n";
    std::cout << "n_points: "     << parsed.n_points    << "\n";
    for (auto& p : parsed.points)
        std::cout << " - point { " << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << " }\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Description: 'FILE_DESCRIPTION'
n_edges: 523459
n_points: 45267393
 - point { -91.196, 30.4248, 6.90671 }
 - point { -91.1937, 30.4239, 0.260769 }
 - point { -91.1983, 30.4257, 11.4345 }
 - point { -91.2007, 30.4267, 8.25918 }
 - point { -91.203, 30.4276, 2.22043 }
 - point { -91.2044, 30.4259, 3.00127 }
 - point { -91.1963, 30.4232, 13.453 }
 - point { -91.1942, 30.4215, 7.89157 }
```

I've made some assumptions, but not too many (you didn't explain any of the input format...). NE/NP could have been short for "number of edges, number of points" (no clue, really).

Note that

1. if you want to validate that the index of the points is sequentially increasing, you can:

   ```
   (omit[int_(boost::phoenix::ref(counter)++)] >> auto_) % eol,
   ```
2. if you want to accept exactly *n* points (e.g. `n_points` or your 'NP'), you'd write

   ```
   repeat(n_points) [omit[int_] >> auto_ >> eol],
   ```

See both combined **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f5739cc8922decb)</kbd>** (where it reads only 6 points out of the input because `n_points` is 6).

Comment: Added some advanced validation examples to the answer. Note my example includes error handling and reporting. Spirit has iterator adaptors that can give you line/column number information.

Comment: This is very good material also, if I could accept both answers I would. I upvoted yours. You are correct in assuming NP is number of points and NE is number of triangle elements. This data represents a Delaunay triangulated mesh.